# composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.* AppNameHere does not create folder/directory - how to fix it

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-9

I am running:
composer `create-project laravel/laravel:^9.* AppNameHere`
the console looks like finish successfully but there is not folder/directory created in the selected location, why?
I have re-installed multiples times composer, update it and so on, I verified the variables of the system as well, everything look fine to me but I cannot install any new project.

I ran: `composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.* AppNameHere`
I was expenting to see a new folder with the Laravel9.* project in the location.
console "finish succefully" but there is not project created, the folder is missing.

Comment: composer didn't like it when I used a '*' in the version string, so maybe that's your problem?  Maybe try with an actual version number.

Comment: `^9.*` - why do you try to use such a strange constraint? Also, if you want to use a `*` on the shell, you should quote it most of the time, expect you want it to match the files in the current folder

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the game, but I had the same issue. The syntax that works with composer 2.6, according to the man command, is this one:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel app_name_here "9.*" --arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **Check your file permissions**: Make sure that you have the necessary permissions to create a new directory in the location where you're running the composer create-project command. If you're not sure, try running the command with administrative privileges.
2. **Check your disk space**: Make sure that you have enough disk space to create a new Laravel project directory.
3. **Try a different version of Laravel**: If you're still having issues with the Laravel 9 version, try creating a project with a different version of Laravel. For example, you can try running composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.* AppNameHere to create a Laravel 8 project.
4. **Specify a specific version of Laravel**: Instead of using the ^9.* wildcard, try specifying a specific version of Laravel in the composer create-project command. For example, you can try `composer create-project laravel/laravel:9.5.0 AppNameHere` to create a project using Laravel 9.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

When I run `composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.* AppNameHere` it literally get `Could not parse version constraint ^9.*: Invalid version string "^9.*"` (see attached image for more info):

[image: composer error]

You can even try a "[semver simulator](https://semver.madewithlove.com/?package=laravel%2Flaravel&constraint=%5E9.*&stability=stable)" and you can see it does not match anything, unless you change `^9.*` to `9.*` (remove `^`).

And most important, **if you read the composer documentation (Versions and constraints)**, you can see that `^9.*` is not valid, but `9.*` is...

Run the command as `composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9 AppNameHere` because `^9` means `9.0.0 <= Laravel version > 10.0.0` (it means it will look for a `9.0.0` version to `10.0.0` but not including `10.0.0` (latest `9.9.9.9.9` whatever is going to be chosen)).

You are saying exactly that: *download a version that is between 9.x but not 10.x+* => `^9.0` or `^9`. You can also use `9.*` (no `^`) and it will mean: *download any version that is `9.x.x`*, but always prefer `^9` instead of `*`.